# how we can delete numbers in between two matching pattern using sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a file something like:

```
INSERT INTO abc VALUES (0,'edwe','edwe',NULL,'2017-10-24 03:00:00','2017-10-24 03:00:00'),(1,'City','Delhi',NULL,'2017-10-24 03:00:00','2017-10-24 03:00:00'),(4,'artType','Advice/Opinion',NULL,'2017-10-24 03:00:00','2017-10-24 03:00:00')
```

How can I use a sed command to delete the numbers in between `"("` and `","`(occurrence of first comma only and delete it as well) So that result will become:

```
INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('edwe','edwe',NULL,'2017-10-24 03:00:00','2017-10-24 03:00:00'),('City','Delhi',NULL,'2017-10-24 03:00:00','2017-10-24 03:00:00'),('artType','Advice/Opinion',NULL,'2017-10-24 03:00:00','2017-10-24 03:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sed 's/([0-9][0-9]*,/(/g' yourFile
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17719072)

Comment: @PathikVejani What exactly is the problem? The question basically was "I want a sed command that does ..." and here it is. I don't have the feeling the author of the question is interested in further explanations.

Comment: Shorter is ok too sed 's/[0-9],//g'

Comment: @Socowi you can post this as comment rather than answer

Comment: @PathikVejani That's true, but then the there would be no answer to accept and the question would stay open forever. Feel free to add something to this answer if you think it is to short. Personally, I prefer short answers.

Comment: @PathikVejani There are a few discussions on meta about short answer. As it seems [An answer is an answer. Even if one line is enough.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266955/6770384)